# Cannot save ConfigurationSection in Startup.cs - Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, configurationsection

I cannot save my custom `ConfigurationSection` in my `web.config` file on startup.

I've followed this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32490/Custom-Configuration-Sections-for-Lazy-Coders) for a generic implementation. My unit tests passed, I'm able to save de `ConfigurationSection` in my unit tests!

On application start, I want to build a `ClaimCollection` based on the controller class name and the belonging method names:

**Startup.cs**

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{

    Config = new HttpConfiguration();

    BuildUnityContainer();

    BuildClaimCollection(); <----------------

    ConfigureOAuth(app);

    WebApiConfig.Register(Config);
    app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
    app.UseWebApi(Config);

}

public void BuildClaimCollection()
{

    //config section
    MethodClaimSection methodClaimSection = BaseConfigurationSection<MethodClaimSection>.Open();

    var methods = GetClaimAuthorizedMethods();

    foreach (var method in methods)
    {
        var claimValue = GetClaimValueFromMethodName(method);
        var claim = new MethodClaimElement()
        {
            Type = "Method",
            Value = claimValue
        };

        methodClaimSection.MethodClaims.Add(claim);
    }
    methodClaimSection.Save();
}
```

**BaseConfigurationSection.cs**

```
public abstract class BaseConfigurationSection<T> : ConfigurationSection
             where T : ConfigurationSection, new()
{
    public void Save()
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = BaseConfigurationSection<T>.GetConfiguration();
        T section = (T)config.Sections[typeof(T).Name];

        foreach (var property in this.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.IsDefined(typeof(ConfigurationPropertyAttribute), false))
            {
                section.GetType().InvokeMember(property.Name, BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, section, 
                    new object[] { 
                        .GetType().InvokeMember(property.Name, BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, this, null) 
                        });
            }
        }

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
    }
}
```

When I run the WebApi application I get this error:

> Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'System.Web.Http.HttpServer'.

**Stacktrace:**

> [ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
>       Object name: 'System.Web.Http.HttpServer'.]
>          System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.CheckDisposed() +332772
>          System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.CheckDisposedOrStarted() +13
>          System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.set_InnerHandler(HttpMessageHandler value) +23
>          System.Web.Http.HttpServer.Initialize() +108
>          System.Web.Http.HttpServer.b__b() +31
>          System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitializedCore(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +115
>          System.Threading.LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(T& target, Boolean& initialized, Object& syncLock, Func`1 valueFactory) +72
>          System.Web.Http.HttpServer.EnsureInitialized() +119
>          System.Web.Http.d__0.MoveNext() +276
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +3897072
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() +28
>          System.Web.Http.Owin.d__0.MoveNext() +1139
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +3897072
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
>          Microsoft.Owin.Cors.d__0.MoveNext() +1204
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +3897072
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
>          Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext() +287
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +3897072
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
>          Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +937
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +3897072
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
>          Microsoft.Owin.Security.Infrastructure.d__0.MoveNext() +937
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +3897072
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
>          Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__5.MoveNext() +287
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +3897072
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +58
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult() +26
>          Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.d__2.MoveNext() +272
>          System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() +26
>          Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.Infrastructure.ErrorState.Rethrow() +33
>          Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.StageAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult ar) +150
>          Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.IntegratedPipeline.IntegratedPipelineContext.EndFinalWork(IAsyncResult ar) +42
>          System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +415
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

The Configuration class doesn't have a Dispose method...

How to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't.  Giving the account that is running your app pool write access to the website directory is a very, very bad idea.  Don't try to write to your web.config file.  Read and save this information from a different, safe, location

Comment: In addition to what Will said above, Web.config file is under constant watch. Any change in this file causes app pool recycle. So beaware while changing web.config when application is started.

Comment: Is it a better idea to write to a separate .xml file. Like this [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/readwritexmltutmellli2111282005041517am/readwritexmltutmellli21.aspx) ? Will, do you mean with a 'safe location' a separate file?